# Retain cycle Swift closure

Tags: ios, swift, generics, mvvm, key-value-observing

I'm thinking about using this pattern (or something close to it) to observe changes on a pure `Swift` object.

Does this code have a memory leak?

```
class Person {

   var name: String {
       didSet{
           self.listen?(self)
       }
   }

   var phone: Int {
       didSet{
           self.listen?(self)
       }
   }

   var listen: ((_ person: Person) -> Void)?

   init(withName N: String, andPhone P: Int) {
       self.name = N
       self.phone = P
   }
}

 class HouseHold {

   var people = [Person]()

   let changes: (_ person: Person) -> Void = { person in
       print(person.name)
   }

   init(withPeople P: [Person]){
       self.people = P
       for person in people {
           person.listen = self.changes
       }
   }
}

let jon = Person(withName: "Jon", andPhone: 1232344567)


let thais = Person(withName: "Thais", andPhone: 1232344567)


let apartment = HouseHold(withPeople: [jon, thais])

jon.phone = 1232399999
jon.name = "Jon Smith"
jon.phone = 9999999999
thais.name = "Thais Smith"
```

Also, lets say that instead of `HouseHold` I had a `UIViewController` that listened to changes from the `Person` object in the same way. Would there be a memory leak?

Also, comments on the pattern are welcome. I would love to make use of generics so I don't have to make a function for each property I want to observe. Or pass the whole object like the code currently does.

Note: Compiled in a playground

Note 2: Trying to move to a more MVVM architecture without using [reactive cocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa).

Comment: There's no strong reference cycle, but as one always is with closures, you'd have to be vigilant to make sure to use `weak` or `unowned` capture lists in the `listen` closure. On the broader idea, I get what you're trying to do, but it seems a tad intrusive to have to litter one's model types with `didSet` observers for every property. I wonder if KVO-based approach might be less intrusive (and more flexible).

Answer (score 2):

Your code has no retain cycle. Because:

```
HouseHold has Person, HouseHold has changes, Person has HouseHold.changes.
```

There is no Cycle above.

The cycle will occurs if your code is changed as:

```
person.listen = self
```

The situation is:

```
HouseHold has Person, Person has HouseHold.
```

You could test leaks by checking the `deinit` method:

```
class Person {

    //...

    deinit {
        print("Person deinited")
    }
}

class HouseHold {

    //...

    deinit {
        print("HouseHold deinited")
    }
}
```